# Conversion of the Gauss law $\nabla \cdot E = \frac{\rho } {\epsilon_0}$ into integral form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-analysis, vector-fields

This may be physics related but I think it belongs here because I have some doubt about mathematical operators we have gauss law in differential form as $$\nabla \cdot E = \frac{\rho } {\epsilon_0}$$ now I want to convert it in integral form so I wrote it as  $$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0 }$$
Now I multiplied it with $dxdydz$
So
$$\frac{\partial E_x . dxdydz}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_y.dxdydz}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial E_z.dxdydz}{\partial z} = \frac{\rho dxdydz}{\epsilon_0 }$$
Which becomes 
$$\int{\partial E_x .dydz+ \partial E_y.dxdz+ \partial E_z.dxdy} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0 }$$

Which takes form of 
$$\int \vec{E}.\vec{ds}= \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

So was my process correct? Does 
$$\frac{ dxdydz}{\partial x}= dydz ?$$

Comment: Basically, you're going back from Maxwell's first equation $\nabla \cdot E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ to Gauss' law $\Phi_E = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$. As Siminore has pointed out, your notation is a bit problematic.

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). Your approach looks fine, but I would not say that
$$
\frac{dx\, dy\, dz}{\partial x} = dy \, dz,
$$
since it is so meaningless that it would deserve a whole theory to make it rigorous. Since $\nabla \cdot E$ is the divergence of $E$, and since $Q=\int \rho\, dx\, dy\, dz$, just apply the divergence theorem.